# How to change boot image

Tags: boot, gnome, 13.10, bootloader

How do i change the image that appears during boot back to the ubuntu default? I had installed gnome desktop before and after uninstall it had left it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a terminal and type `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth`. No select the theme you want to use.